# Error in wrapping phaser app in cocoon.io

Tags: ios, ipad, phaser-framework, cocoonjs

I have created a game in Phaser and it runs file on my local machine via XAMPP. I have reshuffled my files to align to the Cocoon structure as per their example (basically just used the default Cocoon template, switched out a few files and editor the config.xml file with my own params), successfully compiled the app via Cocoon.io cloud service and created the .ipa file which I have put onto my device (the iPad mini). However, when I run the file I get a black screen.

I downloaded and installed the developer app on my iPad and dropped my zipped game into it. Then I ran the game via canvas+ and got these errors - the first when I run the app, the ones in red when I look at the debug.

When I compile to a native IOS app and launch, I just goes to a black screen.

Any ideas what is going on? Completely at loss on this one.

Max.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just realised that when working with the Cocoon development app you only need to move the www folder not the whole app folder as you do when compiling the app.